# c++ array full with dynamic structures

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

How can i create an array of size 5 full with dynamic structures in such a way where i can delete the array element [2] for example but not destroying the array [4]?

```
Struct Bullet
{
 int x, y, width, height, velocity;
};

Struct Shooting
{
Bullet charger[MAX_SHOT];
Bullet *shoot;
};

int main()
{
for(int i = 0; i<MAX_SHOT; i++)
{
shoot = new Bullet;
charger[i] = shoot;
}
```

What i want is a way where for example when a bullet hits something or goes away i could destroy it but not destroying the charger.
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, honestly your question is unclear and pretty rough.  The code you have doesn't make a lot of sense either.  I'm offering decent advice, but I am looking at your code closer and it wouldn't compile at all.  If you want to ask this, I strongly suggest you re-phrase your question and spend some more time thinking through the problem and what you really want to solve at a higher level (you don't seem to understand the code well enough to describe it in an implementable way.)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
  Your friends here are vector, remove_if, and erase.
 */

#include<vector> // where vector lives.
#include<algorithm> // where remove_if lives.

using std::vector; 
using std::remove_if;

struct Bullet
{
    int x, y, velocity;
    // Note: I left out width and height because I did not use them at all.
};

struct Ship
{
    int x, y, velocity;
};

int const max_shots_in_air= 10;
vector<Bullet> shots_in_air;

// I'm just using a fixed-place Ship as a place to get the starting x and y for each Bullet.
Ship ship{10,10,0};
int const max_bullet_height= 100;
int const bullet_velocity= 5;

void fire_shot()
{
    if(shots_in_air.size() < max_shots_in_air)
    {
        Bullet new_bullet{ship.x, ship.y, bullet_velocity};
        shots_in_air.push_back(new_bullet);
    }
}

void move_bullets()
{
    //First move all the bullets.
    for(auto& current_bullet : shots_in_air)
    {
        current_bullet.y+= current_bullet.velocity;
    }
    //Next check for bullets that need removal
    shots_in_air.erase(remove_if(shots_in_air.begin()
            , shots_in_air.end()
            , [] (Bullet const& b)
            {return b.y > max_bullet_height;}))
        ;
}


void game_loop()
{
    bool in_game= true;
    while(in_game)
    {
        fire_shot();
        move_bullets();
        // do whatever else
    }
}


int main()
{
    game_loop();
}
```